# Attach debugger to starting process for both managed and native code

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

While my process is starting (not yet fully up and running), I'd like to attach debugger to it. I've used `Debugger.Launch()` construction at the beginning of the initialization code to start Visual Studio in debug mode. Unfortunately only the managed type of code is selected for debug. How to force debugger to debug also the native one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found alternative way. Select project properties on the c# project. Choose debug tab. Select your application in start external program and select enable native code debugging. Press F5.